# Excluding String Matches Based on a Single Character Difference

Tags: regex, python-2.7, regex-lookarounds

I have multiple strings.  Here are three representative examples:

```
1. Fridays, Saturdays, 7:30 a.m.-12:45 p.m.
2. Mondays, Wednesdays, Fridays, 9:30 a.m.
3. Mondays, Thursdays-Saturdays, 7:30-10:30 p.m.
```

What I would like to do is create a regular expression that matches the first two strings (times included, which I've already written), but not the third.  The only major difference is that the third string includes a day range (`Thursdays-Saturdays`) -- i.e., it includes a hyphen b/w the days themselves.

I have tried and failed to complete this using lookarounds - tho I believe [based on what I've read](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-lookarounds.html) that lookarounds are the correct tool (for python at least).  Here is what I have ([live demo here](http://regex101.com/r/mJ3hE4/1)) - but it matches everything rather than just the first two strings:

```
[MTWFS]\w.*days,\s1?\d(?::\d\d)?(?:\s[ap]\.m\.)?(?:-1?\d(?::\d\d)?(?:\s[ap]\.m\.))?
```

I have literally tried every conceivable iteration I can think of.  I simply cannot figure out how to match the "Days, Days, [repeating "Days," however many times], Time" paradigm - tho I assume it's simple as I am very new to regex and it seems rather basic.  Thank you for any assistance!

Comment: Try a lazy match and/or leave out the `.` - http://regex101.com/r/mJ3hE4/2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following regexp does it:

```
^(?:(?:Mon|Tues|Wednes|Thurs|Fri|Satur|Sun)days,\s*)+\d{1,2}:\d\d [ap]\.m\.(?:-\d{1,2}:\d\d [ap]\.m\.)?$
```

It matches a series of day names followed by comma and optional whitespace, then followed by either a single time or two times separated with `-`.

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/nH3dE8/2)

Answer (score 2):

Since you want to exclude strings that contain a day range (e.g. `Thursdays-Saturdays`) and not worrying about capturing certain parts of each string, you could possibly do this using a **Negative Lookahead**.

```
^(?!.*(?:Mon|Tues|Wednes|Thurs|Fri|Satur|Sun)days-).+$
```

[**Working Demo**](https://eval.in/182179)

Answer (score 1):

For the weekday part, I would write out the desired days so funny values (like `Suburbandays`) don't sneak their way in there:

```
^(?:(?:(?:Mon|Tues|Wednes|Thurs|Fri|Satur|Sun)days,\s*)+)
```

I would also try to validate the times (so `13:00 a.m.` gets rejected):

```
 ((?:-?(?:[1-9]:|1[012]:)(?:[0-5]\d)\s*[ap]\.m\.){1,2})
```

[Original regex101 demo](http://regex101.com/r/mJ3hE4/4) as well as an [updated regex101 demo](http://regex101.com/r/mJ3hE4/5) (with inline comments).